# Navigation Helper Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm a bit stuck, and probably not understanding AR properly.  Here's what I've got:

```
module PagesHelper

  def page_loop(pages)
    output = ""

    pages.each do |page|
      output << "<li><a href=\"" << page.title << "\">" << page.title << "</a>"

      children = page.children

      if children.size > 0
        output << "<ul>"
        page_loop(children)
        output << "</ul>"
      end

      output << "</li>"
    end

    return output
  end

  def navigation_list
    parent_pages = Page.where("parent_page_id IS NULL").order("title")

    output = "<ul>"
    output << page_loop(parent_pages)
    output << "</ul>"
  end
end
```

And then the following in the model:

```
def children
  Page.where("parent_page_id = ?", id)
end
```

For some reason it returns the following output, where I've got two pages, test, and another with its parent_page_id set to the id of the test page.

```
<ul><li><a href="test">test</a><ul></ul></li></ul>
```

So it's getting the next `<ul>` elements, but doesn't loop over the pages.

Am I misunderstanding AR methods?  I'm expecting an `<li>` element in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah.  Silly bug.

```
  if children.size > 0
    output << "<ul>"
    output << page_loop(children)
    output << "</ul>"
  end
```

Fixed.